# importing xlsx package shows module not found

Tags: reactjs, webpack, export, xlsx, modulenotfounderror

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'process/browser' in '/Users/nigelng/oxpay-merchant-portal-fe/node_modules/xlsx'
Did you mean 'browser.js'?

I have installed xlsx 0.18.5 npm package to export xlsx files, I found out that's a webpack issue (https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/2527), but the solutions didn't work for me.

do anyone experience the same error?

Answer (score 0):

The way I fixed this was by using the package @craco/craco so you can manually change the webpack config file without ejecting create-react-app (since that is permanent). Once craco is installed create a file in the root directory named craco.config.js and then copy and paste this configuration, should fix your problem:

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.m?js/,
            resolve: {
                fullySpecified: false
            }
          }
        ]
      },
    }
  }
};
```

Make sure to change your start script to "craco start" and you should be off to the races.